# How to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer to the same control simultaneously?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer, simultaneous

It is similar to this question:

[iPhone iOS how to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer to the same control and prevent conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728632/iphone-ios-how-to-add-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-and-uitapgesturerecognizer)

but my problem is more complex.

I want to implement the same behavior you see in iOS 8 on iPad. I mean page grid in Safari.

The problem: one view should respond to both long press and tap gesture recognizers. The following things should work:

1)close button accepts clicks

2)when the tap begins the selected view should perform scale animation

3)on long press the selected view becomes draggable

If I don't use `(requireGestureRecognizerToFail:)` then tap gesture doesn't work. If I use this method then everything works but the long press events take place with huge delays.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` method.

```
//Single tap
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapDouble = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(handleTapGestureForSearch:)];
        tapDouble.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapDouble.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapDouble];

        //long press
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressRecognizer:)];
        longPressGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
        longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
        [longPressGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapDouble];
        longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

This means Long press gesture wait for the single Tap.

Comment: read the question first. Especially for you in this case long press gesture waits too much time.

Comment: If so then Instead of Long press use the NSTimer

Comment: I can't understand your idea with timer. Could you say a lit bit more about it?

Comment: I mark this as answer to close the question only. You have just repeated the question description but with code.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov you cannot mark an answer as correct only to close the question, that goes against the whole point of using StackOverflow. The answer is incorrect and should be called out so.

Answer (score 0):

You can add time to the long press gesture.

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ontappLongPressGesture:)];
 longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration=0.6;
 longPressGesture.delegate=self;
 [cell.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSelected:)];
//[gesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPressGesture]; 
 gesture.delegate=self;
 [cell.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

 also you need to set this delegate to work both gesture together
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer  *)otherGestureRecognizer 
 {
 return YES;
 }
```

Comment: doesn't work because this method is called too often